# Combiner function in Apache Hadoop with Gora

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch, gora, nutch2

I have a simple Hadoop, Nutch 2.x, Hbase cluster. I have to write a MR job that will find some statistics. It is two step job i.e., I think I need combiner function also. In simple Hadoop jobs, its not a big problem as a lot of guide is given e.g., [this one](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-combiner-example/). But I could not found any option to use combiner with Gora. My statistics will be added to pages in Hbase that's why I could not about Gora (I think ). Following is the code snippet where I expect to add com

```
GoraMapper.initMapperJob(job, query, pageStore, Text.class, WebPage.class,
        My_Mapper.class, null, true);


    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    // === Reduce ===
    DataStore<String, WebPage> hostStore = StorageUtils.createWebStore(
        job.getConfiguration(), String.class, WebPage.class);
    GoraReducer.initReducerJob(job, hostStore, My_Reducer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the combiner with Gora, but does this work (or what error does it show)?:

```
GoraReducer.initReducerJob(job, hostStore, My_Reducer.class);
job.setCombinerClass(My_Reducer.class);
```

---

Edit: Created an issue at [Apache's Jira about the Combiner](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-563).

Comment: I have tested it but in this case the job is marked completed after combiner part and reducer part is not executed